# Python Json value overwritten by last value

Tags: python, json, loops

```
lista =
[{Identity: joe,
summary:[
  {distance: 1, time:2, status: idle},
  {distance:2, time:5, status: moving}],
{unit: imperial}]
```

I can pull the data easily and put in pandas. The issue is, if an identity has multiple instances of, say idle, it takes the last value, instead of summing together.

my code...

```
zdrivershours = {}
zdistance = {}
zstophours = {}

For driver in resp:
   driverid[driver['AssetID']] = driver['AssetName']
      for value in [driver['SegmentSummary']]:
         for value in value:
           if value['SegmentType'] == 'Motion':
             zdriverhours[driver['AssetID']] = round(value['Time']/3600,2)
           if value['SegmentType'] == 'Stop':
             zstophours[driver['AssetID']] = round(value['IdleTime']/3600,2)
           zdistance[driver['AssetID']] = value['Distance']
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you're having trouble with. This is pseudo-code

Comment: You are initiliazing `distance` as a dict. If you want a numeric value, initilize it as `distance = 0` and then every time that the `status == 'moving'` do `distance = distance + value['distance']`

Comment: @ArthurKing i have updated the code.

Comment: Maybe is a typo, but you are missing ' on `zdriverhours[driver[AssetID']]`

Comment: good catch @GonzaloOdiard indeed typo here, it's fine in python

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard i tried ur work but i'm getting empty value

`for value in value:

   distance = 0

   distance = += value ['Distance']

    zdistance[driver['AssetID']] = distance
`

if i move the distance = 0 out of loop, it sums distances for all drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the summatory of distance for every driver replace:

```
zdistance[driver['AssetID']] = value['Distance']
```

by

```
if driver['AssetID'] in zdistance:
    zdistance[driver['AssetID']] = zdistance[driver['AssetID']] + value['Distance']
else:
    zdistance[driver['AssetID']] = value['Distance']
```